# How can I get the object count for a model in Django's templates?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm my Django application I'm fetching all the objects for a particular model like so:

```
secs = Sections.objects.filter(order__gt = 5)
```

I pass this varbiles to my templates and i can access all the properties of the Model like `section.name`, `section.id`, etc.

There is a model called `Books` which has a FK to the `Sections` model. When i iterate over the `secs` varible in my template, how can i access the count of Books for each Section? Something like `{{ sec.Books.count }}`??

Thank you

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If `Books` has a ForeignKey to `Sections`, then Django will automatically create a reverse relationship from Sections back to Books, which will be called `books_set`. This is a Manager, which means you can use `.filter()`, `.get()` and `.count()` on it - and you can use these in your template.

```
{{ sec.books_set.count }}
```

(By the way, you should use singular nouns for your model names, not plurals - `Book` instead of `Books`. An instance of that model holds information for one book, not many.)

Answer (score 17):

Additionally to what Daniel said, Django creates reverse relationships automatically (as Daniel said above) unless you override their names with the related_name argument. In your particular case, you would have something like:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section, related_name="books")
```

Then you can access the section's books count in the template by:

```
{{ sec.books.count }}
```

As you intimated in your question.

Answer (score 7):

As for a **2019** answer. I would suggest making use of `related_name` while making your `ForeignKey` to look like that:

```
section = models.ForeignKey(Section, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='books')
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
{{ section.books.count }}
```

or

```
{{ section.books|length }}
```

Comment: {{ section.books|length }} does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

For Django 3.0, If the `Book` model is related to `Section` model,

```
{{ sec.books_set.all.count }}
```

The working is already mentioned in [the answer by @Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3396090/8388057)

Answer (score 0):

```
menus = Menu.objects.filter(parent__name__isnull=True)

{% for menu in menus %}

{% if menu.childs.count > 0 %}
...

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Your suggestion would be even more helpful if you used the model names and variables from the question. It's not clear this really answers the question.