# Access Model.objects methods from Django templates

Tags: python, django, templates

Let's say I have a "Person" model.
How can I display the number of persons in my system in a template?
In standard code, I would do: `Person.objects.count()`.
But how to do this in a template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You save the output of `Person.objects.count()` in a variable and pass it on to your template from the corresponding view.

Comment: This surely works but I would like to avoid passing variables from the views to the templates when it's not meaningful. More, I saw that it is doable with related objects: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395863/get-object-count-in-django-templates

Comment: Well, since the code at hand does some processing that needs to be then displayed in a template, passing its output as a variable sounds quite meaningful. What is being done with the related objects requires for you to pass at least the parent object through the view, then you can access its various methods, like `group.person_set.count` but the template _will_ need some starting point for you to give to it.