# how to display number of comments in django

Tags: django

I'm just little bit confused, I have two models

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyProfile)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, null=True, blank=True, related_name="commented_post")
    text = models.TextField()
```

And

```
class Post(models.Model):
    #comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment)if I do this I get an error but how do I display the number of comments? I was thinking to do {{post.comment.count}}
```

I tried adding the following function under comment model

```
@property
    def get_comment_count(self):
        return self.comment.count
```

but this doesn't do the job, I think I have to use something like `{{comment.post.count}}`maybe...any help please..

Comment: Shouldn't you be adding that method in the `Post` model, since you want the comment count for each post?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the object count for a model in Django's templates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395863/how-can-i-get-the-object-count-for-a-model-in-djangos-templates)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to get the number of comments for a specific post, you can do `comments_count = Comment.objects.filter(post=mypost).count()`

Comment: this goes into views.py right? and then I should use comments_count in my template

Comment: This is completely unnecessary...Assuming a post object is already in the context, you don't need to add anything else to *views.py*. You can access the comment count with...  `{{post_object_name.commented_post.count}}`